# Pepper robot: Get description of installed behavior

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

I'm currently building a behavior for Pepper where I want to find the installed behaviors and then display them on the tablet including the description given in the project properties. From the [ALBehaviorManager](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/core/albehaviormanager-api.html) I can find the installed behaviors easily, but that only gives me the name of the behavior. How can I get the description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check on the module [PackageManager](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/core/packagemanager-api.html?highlight=package%20manager#PackageManager::package). With the function *packages()*, you can have all the information on applications. I think that this function returns a json. You can also get the description of a specific applications with *package(uuid_application)*.

Comment: Nice, it was a question  I'm asking myself one week ago ! Thank you!